# How do i change the color of value in a datatable cell when there is a change in the value of that cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am fetching json data through ajax for my datatable and performing a ajax reload every 2 seconds which updates the datatable values but I want to change the color of all the values that changed during the reload. How can I do that?

I would like the output to be like this
https://www.dailyfx.com/forex-rates?ref=TopRates

This is my code

```
<table id="example" class="pgnTable table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First value</th>
      <th>Second value</th>
      <th>Third value</th>
      <th>Fourth value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
        "url": "/pktd",
        "dataType": "json",
        "dataSrc": "data",
        "contentType": "application/json"
      },
      "columns": [{
          "data": "first"
        },
        {
          "data": "second"
        },
        {
          "data": "third"
        },
        {
          "data": "fourth"
        }
      ]
    });
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set a CSS Class when you see a value change, with [CSS Keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) you can also add some color changing animations like the forex site.

JQuery has functions built in for adding and removing classes based on an elements ID like you have above.

Comment: How do i get the values from datatable and check for a change? Is there a method in jquery's datatables to do that? I'm using jquery datatables for the first time so consider me a newbie.

Comment: You might have to run the ajax call separately then feed in the response from that into the datatable after checking for differences. I dont have much experience with Datatables either sorry.